# Maven skip tests specified in -Dtest

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to run `mvn test` on a submodule from the parent module, specifying the tests (actually 1 test) that I want to run.

the command:

```
mvn -pl :tika-parsers test -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dtest=org.apache.tika.detect.TestContainerAwareDetector
```

The problem is that for some reason no test is running.

The build report:

```
...
...
...
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) @ tika-parsers ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\user\Code\Python\BugMiner\tested_project\tika\tika-parsers\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
... ... ...
```

When Im running:

```
mvn -pl :tika-parsers test
```

All the tests are running including the one I specified

The build report:

```
...
...
...
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) @ tika-parsers ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\user\Code\Python\BugMiner\tested_project\tika\tika-parsers\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running org.apache.tika.detect.TestContainerAwareDetector
Tests run: 15, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.293 sec
Running org.apache.tika.embedder.ExternalEmbedderTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 sec
Running org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypesTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.016 sec
Running org.apache.tika.mime.MimeTypeTest
...
...
...
```

Can anyone show me what is the proper command?

Comment: Are you sure that the path in your `-Dtest` argument is correct? 
I can be a lazy person, so I would do `-Dtest=TestContainerAwareDetector` to test that file (without paths). Maven is capable to figure out which one to run at its own.

Comment: Tried  -Dtest=TestContainerAwareDetector. Didn't work

Comment: If you run `mvn test -DfailIfNoTests=false -Dtest=org.apache.tika.detect.TestContainerAwareDetector` (no project specified), what happen ?

Comment: It's a bug in [surefire version 2.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531219/maven-surefire-2-12-does-not-run-a-specific-test-using-dtest-parameter). I guess upgrading will fix the problem...

Comment: Do you know by any chance how can I specify the surefire version from the command prompt?

Comment: @RotemBarak it is displayed somewhere in the logs:
`[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12:test (default-test) @ tika-parsers ---`
It looks like you have the buggy version 2.12 ;-)

Comment: I see. Do you know how can I change it? Using only the command line?

Answer (score 1):

This is a surefire [version 2.12 bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531219/maven-surefire-2-12-does-not-run-a-specific-test-using-dtest-parameter).

Upgrade the surefire plugin in the `pom.xml` file:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
               ...
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Do you know how can I specify it from the cmd?

Comment: @RotemBarak I don't think it's possible. Why don't you update the `pom.xml` ?

Comment: Because I'm running mvn command on external project, so I'm really trying to avoid changing their pom.xml files. Would you recommand trying to run a script that would change the version of the surefire plugin?

Comment: @RotemBarak Not sure to understand what you want to achieve... But if that external project is still maintained by someone, they should really understand that moving from surefire `2.12` to `2.12.1` won't break anything...

Comment: @RotemBarak Maybe you could copy their `pom.xml` to `mypom.xml`, then edit this `mypom.xml` with new surefire version, then run it with `mvn -f mypom.xml ...`

Comment: Ok, I think you gave me good orientaion. I'll see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

I think your command is good and shall work, try downgrading OR upgrading your surefire version and this shall solve the problem for you.

Comment: Do you know how can I change versions from the command prompt?